# How to have Matlab recognize my $PATH?

Tags: macos, matlab, shell

I am using the GraphViz interface for Matlab [(link)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21652-graphviz4matlab), and noticed that Matlab's calls to the shell (e.g., via `system` or `!`) return with errors (command not found) when attempting to call `graphviz` or `neato` or other related names, which are perfectly valid when called from my own default shell (bash, using Terminal on OSX).

Well, I installed graphviz to my system using homebrew, so it should work fine -- I tested `!brew -v` from Matlab and it doesn't work either! So, I checked my path. In bash, `echo $PATH` returns

`/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin`

while in Matlab, `!echo $PATH` returns `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

So, this is potentially causing my problems. That said,

1) How can I have Matlab either automatically sync the correct path, or do so once-per-startup? (i.e., so I could put the code into `startup.m`)

2) Can someone diagnose what causes Matlab to not find the correct environment variables, and whether this is a global problem or likely specific to my configuration?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you try what they discuss in this exchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255609

Comment: This approach will work, but it will become cumbersome to have to manually tweak the `PATH` for each Matlab session.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to repeat the edit.

Comment: I'm pretty confident this has to do with the fact that on OS X path can be defined in many different ways - my guess would be matlab  ignores the definition in environment.plist

Comment: What could the source be then for Matlab's `PATH`?

Comment: I found this http://superuser.com/questions/31353/path-in-vim-doesnt-match-terminal - it seems to be a common issue with macs that the dot files are not respected when you start an app via finder.  Unfortunately i just know about workarounds not the reason.

Comment: @bdecaf For the record, after following your link and relying heavily on the answer (http://superuser.com/a/69190), it looks like Matlab only checks `/etc/profile`, so I manually added to the top of the matlab executable, `source $HOME/.bash_profile` to get my user settings, and `for f in /etc/paths.d/*; do PATH=$(<$f):$PATH; done` to emulate OSX's use of paths.d. This worked splendidly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm still curious what in the world causes this to happen for, apparently, a wide variety of applications on OSX! Hopefully there is a global workaround (short of sticking user profile settings into the global ones).

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation for what you are seeing is that Matlab is being run on your OSX distribution under a different user than your own profile.

When you do an `echo $PATH` from Matlab, it is showing you the `PATH` for the user under which Matlab is running.  However, when you do `echo $PATH` from the command line, it is showing you the `PATH` for **your** user profile.

To correct this, please investigate the way you are running Matlab, and make sure you are running it as yourself (or as a user who has the correct `PATH` settings).

**Update:**

I downloaded Matlab 8.5 on my Fedora box at home.  I was unable to run it unless I did so using `sudo su` followed by `./matlab`.  What I observed is that Matlab caches the value of the `PATH` variable of the Linux user who launched it for the entire session.  Changing the `PATH` during a Matlab session did not change the output of `!echo $PATH` in Matlab.

Please try to reproduce the following on your setup:

1. Type `sudo su` from a Terminal window
2. `echo $PATH` and record what you see
3. `./matlab` Start Matlab
4. `!echo $PATH` from within Matlab.  What you see should match Step 2.
5. Kill Matlab, and do `export PATH=$PATH:/newpath/` from the same Terminal
6. Repeat steps 3 and 4, and you should see the new `PATH` value in Matlab

Comment: I'm running Matlab in the most mundane way, double-clicking the application icon. Activity Monitor tells me the corresponding process has my account (an admin account) as the User. Terminal is also run from my account. I'm not sure whether the shell runs under a process distinct from Terminal.

Comment: Inspiration: Might it be possible that Matlab caches the `PATH` variable during installation/first run?  If so, would you happen to know if your user `PATH` at some earlier time resembled what Matlab is displaying?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I wouldn't doubt it. The executable `/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/matlab` , when run via `./matlab -e`, lists all environmental variables generated. This includes `SHELL=/bin/bash` and the correct (longer) `PATH`. Ah, but I ran it from Terminal! Of course it would get the correct info. Hmm.

Comment: I can't use my modified launch script as root ($HOME gives errors), and when I use the original launch script, Matlab bugs me about product activation / I can't get to the command line. My $PATH as root looks identical to my $PATH as usual, though. Also: does this tell us about why launching Matlab as usual doesn't let it access $PATH from the perspective of the user who launched it?

Comment: What I could do is, for example, just follow your instructions using my user account rather than switching to root. Here's what I found: opening the original unmodified matlab executable, from Terminal with my usual user account, always gives the correct path (including adjusting if I append /newpath/). So, "double-click opening" really looks like the culprit.

Comment: Can you check the configuration settings of the executable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean! BTW there are several other ad hoc solutions people have found (http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/02/08/starting-matlab-from-the-os-x-dock/#comment-7236) that may shed light on the issue at large. Also, we may want to take this discussion to chat rather than a comment thread. [: